# JUnit tests fail due to exception "Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil"

Tags: java, junit, log4j, log4j2

I have a Java EE web service that I just converted to use log4j2 over v1. My JUnit tests are failing with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:61)
```

The exact line it's failing on is `LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyEndpoint.class);`. I've searched high and low and cannot find any solution to this nor this being a common problem. My dependencies are:
junit 4.12
mockito-core 2.15.0
log4j-core and log4j-api 2.19.0

Due to other dependencies I still have log4j1 on the classpath, however excluding it from the build doesn't change the outcome.

I cannot post the whole source code as this is a company project.

Comment: `log4j-core` needs to be at least the same version as the API. Can you add the whole stacktrace (i.e. including the "Caused by")? Can you run your test with `-Dlog4j2.debug` and include the output?

Comment: I ended up resolving the issue (see my answer). I do remember that there was no "caused by" section of the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I found I had to add `org.osgi:osgi.core:8.0.0` to my list of dependencies. If anyone knows why, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I guess you already had an old `osgi.core` artifact on your classpath and Log4j2 tried (and failed) to retrieve its services through OSGI. cf. [LOG4J2-3642](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3642)

Comment: Thanks for the Jira link! Glad to see I'm not the only one running into this :)